# Browserify module order in output - Differing between dev and build server

Tags: browserify

We've got a browserify step in our gulp process and the output of this is differing between dev and our build server.

The output on the build server contains a module at the top of the output file that `requires` a file further down in the source. This seems to be causing an issue and we get `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'module-name'` in Chrome dev tools.

The output in dev however has our module in question further down in the source.

In both cases, the module definition appears further down in the source than the line `require`ing it.

I've checked the versions of npm, node, babel, babelify, browserify, vinyl-source-stream. These are all the same in dev and on our build server.

**What could be causing this issue?**

The gulp task in question looks like this:

```
gulp.task('esnext', function(done) {

  var files = glob('content/scripts/**/*.js', function(err, files) {

    files = files.filter(function(file) {
      return file.indexOf('modules') <= -1;
    });

    browserify({
        entries: files,
        debug: true,
        paths: ['./content/scripts', './content/scripts/modules', './content/libs']
      })
      .transform(babelify)
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('esnext-temp.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/global/scripts/'))
      .on('end', done);
  });
});
```

**Update**

I've removed the file filter from the gulp task that that seems to have partly solved the problem. The files are more similar now except for the following:

Dev:

`},{"some-module":7,"some-other-module":18,"another-module":54}],25:[function(require,module,exports){`

Build Server:

`},{"some-module":undefined,"some-other-module":undefined,"another-module":undefined}],25:[function(require,module,exports){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per : https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1271#issuecomment-104897413

> to your immediate problem, I'd try switching all the relative paths to
>   absolute paths and/or setting a basedir

Adding the basedir to browserify seems to have solved this problem:

```
browserify({
        entries: files,
        debug: true,
        basedir: __dirname,
        paths: ['./content/scripts', './content/scripts/modules', './content/libs']
      })
```